# Permutations of single array in expected array of arrays

Tags: ruby

```
new_variant_permutations = all_value_arrays[1..].inject(all_value_arrays[0]) { |m, v| m.product(v).map { |perm| perm.flatten.sort } }
```

This line if given an `all_value_arrays` which is basically an array of arrays like `[[1,2],[3,4]]` returns possible permutations such as `[[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4]]`
However if all_value_arrays  is a single array inside an array like `[[1,2,3,4]]`, instead of getting my expected `[[1],[2],[3],[4]]` I get `[1,2,3,4]`
and this causes a problem with my code later on
How can i avoid this happening and maintain the consistency of array of arrays as in my first example? TIA

Comment: Why do you expect the output `[[1],[2],[3],[4]]` with the input `[[1,2,3,4]]`? Are you trying to return all permutations of any length?

Comment: I'm trying to return permutations of my entry arrays that include one and exactly one value from the values in each of my entry arrays.

Comment: I have hotfixed by succeeding with `new_variant_permutations = new_variant_permutations.map { |entry| entry.is_a?(Array) ? entry : [entry] }` but I'd rather fix my initial code.

Comment: I think this should work: `all_value_arrays.reduce(&:product).map(&:flatten)`. Try it out and if it works I'll make it an answer.

Comment: `[[1,2,3,4]].reduce(&:product).map(&:flatten)` doesn't work so no :(

Comment: Whoops. Try `.reduce(&:product).map { |perm| [perm].flatten }` instead.

Comment: That seems to work for both my cases yes! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one liner should do what you're asking for (return an array of arrays representing the cartesian product of the input arrays).

```rb
all_value_arrays.reduce(&:product).map { |perm| [perm].flatten }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def doit(arr)
  arr.first.product(*arr.drop(1))
end
```

```
doit [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
  #=> [[1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6],
  #    [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 6], [2, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

```
doit [[1,2,3,4]]
  #=> [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```